# Integrating OpenID into Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, openid

I've tried integrating [sfPHPOpenIdPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPHPOpenIdPlugin) but that hit a dead-end since it's built for Symfony 1.2 and relies on deprecated PHP functionality; I also had a go with [sfGoogleLoginPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGoogleLoginPlugin) which did authenticate correctly but lacks extended capability to retrieve user details (+ would restrict me to Google; obviously).

I'm thinking the most viable solution is to link in one of the various PHP libraries available into my model.

I'm wondering if anyone else has had any success/tips with such an integration and what libraries to consider?

---

**Update:**

Having gone off this as a concept I switched to using sfTwitterAuthPlugin for my portfolio and any Symfony-based web apps I build.

For anyone interested, the version on the official plugins website lacks some useful functionality, I'm actively maintaining improvements at https://github.com/stevelacey/sfTwitterAuthPlugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually [sfPHPOpenIdPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPHPOpenIdPlugin) was updated yesterday and is compatible with Symfony 1.4.

Comment: Hah! I'd just about got the 1.2 version working by patching php-openid to a version compliant with PHP 5.3. Thanks for pointing this out though I'll update and report back!

Comment: Whilst I never got around to getting this fully working, I'd still deem this the way to go when integrating OpenID into Symfony.

Comment: Can i use this plugin for googleplus login instead of google login?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to integrate with different authentication providers for a .Net project that I'm working on.  Eventually, I ended using a cloud service from the company [RPXNow](https://rpxnow.com/), which I absolutley love.  It abstracts the details of each provider into a single REST API which is very easy to use.  You can so simple authentication with the free version, but for $10, you get access to extended data, as well as integration with social sites (post to Facebook wall, Tweet on behalf of user, etc).  Of course, users always have the right to restrict these features.

Anyway, not sure how it would integrate with PHP, but it was a snap with .Net/C#.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure that I want to outsource this to a third-party in this manner, or if I'd be happy with the restrictions imposed on the free version; but I will look into this regardless, thanks for your answer!